# How to add data-attr and class from title with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, attributes, title

I have an element on page with title="class className dataAttr".
I want to create a jQuery code which add className to class="className" and dataAttr to data-icon="dataAttr" from title.
Here my code:

```js
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("[title*='class']").addClass(function () {
        return $(this).attr('title');
    }).attr('data-icon', function () {
        str = $(this).attr("title");
        str = str.replace('class', '');
        return str
    }).removeClass('class').removeAttr('title');
});
</script>
```

But this script add className and dataAttr together to class and data-icon too. I think that there will be some condition for space or symbol between className and dataAttr to add it separately. 
I don't know how to do it. Do you know some solutions about that?
I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: Not clear what problem is, especially since no html is provided. Please create a demo that replicates problem as well as outlines expected results

Comment: It is clear. I found a solution. It is bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet works:

```js
 
 $( document ).ready(function() {

 $("[title*='class']").each(function() {
       var title = $(this).attr('title');
       var titleArray = title.split(" ");
       $(this).addClass(titleArray[1]);
       $(this).attr("data-icon", titleArray[2]);
       $(this).removeAttr('title');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p title="class className dataAttr">test</p>
```